# Chain should_receive Possible?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a more terse way to write this rspec code?

```
mailer = double
AdminMailer.should_receive(:request_failed).with(@request).and_return(mailer)
mailer.should_receive(:deliver)
```

I'm envisioning something like this:

```
AdminMailer
  .should_receive(:request_failed)
  .with(@request)
  .should_receive(:deliver)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, but even if it is, I wouldn't recommend it.  Your specs should clearly show what you are expecting of your code, and your first example already does that quite succinctly!

Comment: Yeah, I was in the middle of writing the same exact answer.  Even if it did work, don't do it because it will not be clear what needs to be fixed if either of the assertions fails.